# I am trying to iterate a numpy 2D array in a for loop. why is the output repeating itself

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

please tell what am I doing wrong here
the output is repeated

```
import numpy as np

hj = np.array([[2, 3, 0], [6, 5, 7], [8, 9, 7], [1, 1, 1]])
print(hj)

print("2-D")
grr = hj

for x in grr:
    for y in grr:
        print(grr)
```

I even tried to do
hj = np.arange(0, 10).reshape(5, 2)

I also did

```
import numpy as np

hj = np.array([[2, 3, 0], [6, 5, 7], [8, 9, 7], [1, 1, 1]])
# hj = np.arange(0, 10).reshape(5, 2)
# print(hj)

print("2-D")

for x in hj:
    for y in hj:
        print(hj)
```

Comment: Why the loop?  `print(grr)`

Comment: why not? without the loops i can get the output easily, I wanted to experiment, and I know we can Iterate a numpy array.

Comment: When you iterate an array you get the elements of the array.  By doing the `print(grr)` in the loop you are just printing the whole array again and again..  Iterating like this is not going reproduce the 2d layout.  Yes you can iterate **through** an array, but why?  That's just treating it like a list of lists - and is slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [25]: arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

Lets look in more detail at what the variables are in the loop:

```
In [26]: for x in arr:
    ...:     print('%r %r'%(x, arr))
    ...:     for y in x:
    ...:         print('%r %r %r'%(y, x, arr))
    ...: 
array([1, 2]) array([[1, 2],       # a (2,) and (2,2) array
       [3, 4]])
1 array([1, 2]) array([[1, 2],     # a scalar, a (2,) and (2,2)
       [3, 4]])
2 array([1, 2]) array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
array([3, 4]) array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
3 array([3, 4]) array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
4 array([3, 4]) array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

You could use a double list comprehension to produce a list of lists:

```
In [27]: [[y for y in x] for x in arr]
Out[27]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
In [28]: arr.tolist()             # faster
Out[28]: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: ok i see what you did there but can you explain line 27 a little bit, how have you used it. i am getting a little confused are you using it in a for loop? Thank you

Comment: [27] is a `list comprehension`, a python construct that acts like a for loop using list append to collect values.  That is a basic and important Python construct.  `numpy` runs in Python, so you need to know the basic language to use it effectively.

Comment: ohh, great so your code done in jupyter notebook? as i am getting error in pycharm thank you again

Comment: I use `ipython`, related to a notebook, but this should work just as well as a plain script.  I don't know why pycharm should be different.

Answer (score 0):

This loop is wrong:

```
for x in grr:
    for y in grr:
        print(grr)
```

You're basically printing `grr` over and over again. Probably you meant something like this:

```
for x in grr:
    print(x)
```

Comment: print(y) return all the number, i want to return the array in 2D like                                  [[2 3 0]
 [6 5 7]
 [8 9 7]
 [1 1 1]],                                                                                                                              
 if I write                                                                                                                         
'''for x in grr:
    print(grr)''' it still repeats the output

Comment: You need to `print(x)`, not `print(grr)` ;) Check my answer now, @Pranjal.